# Oracle select date range within date range

Tags: oracle, date, select

I have a table that has a start date and end date field.
I would like users to select a date range and return records that are within that range.
I can write a little Java code to do this, but is there a way to do it in an Oracle select?
To make it worse, the end date might be fuzzy... I might know he lives there today, but I'm not sure about next week.

As an example, I have a list of names, addresses, and dates when the 'name' lived at the 'address' (all dates are date datatype)

```
name        address        moved in        moved out     known end date?
jack        123 main st    1/1/2015        12/31/2015    Y
jill        123 main st    1/1/2016        12/31/2016    Y
jeff        123 main st    1/1/2017        12/31/2017    Y
jane        123 main st    1/1/2018        12/31/2018    N (she may still be there)
```

so if I query from 6/1/15 to 6/1/16 I should get jack and jill. For 6/1/17 to 7/1/17 I should get jeff. For 1/28/20 I should get jane since she may still be there.

I would appreciate any clues you could give me. I'd love to do this on the database side.

Comment: What are the data type of columns `moved in` and `moved out`?

Comment: seems that a date range should have the high date in the range >= moved_in, or the low date in the range <= moved_out (or current date if move-out is not known) to cover that overlap. Try to code that and let us know if you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what Michael Broughton said:

```
create table addr (name varchar2(10), address varchar2(20), moved_in date, moved_out date, known_end_date varchar2(1));

insert into addr values ('jack','123 main st',date '2015-01-01',date '2015-12-31','Y');
insert into addr values ('jill','123 main st',date '2016-01-01',date '2016-12-31','Y');
insert into addr values ('jeff','123 main st',date '2017-01-01',date '2017-12-31','Y');
insert into addr values ('jane','123 main st',date '2018-01-01',date '2018-12-31','N');

select *
from addr
where moved_in <= to_date(:end_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
  and (moved_out >= to_date(:start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') or known_end_date = 'N');
```